# Command Execution Location

Tags: linux

Is there a way to know where command typed? I mean when I list the running processes, there are many processes with full path name, but it does not indicated where these process started.

Think about that there is a java application under  /tmp/AppJava.jar   It could be executed under /home/appuser or /home/test by manullay or other script.

Is there a way how to find `java -jar /tmp/AppJava.jar` executed under which directory?

Comment: You are referring to the working directory of a process? That is something private to the process. You cannot query it directly. And a process can simply change its working directory, so what is the point?

Comment: I want to know how any process is started

Comment: In general it is not possible. One could imagine a process starting in some weird directory, then `chdir`-ing to another, and deleting the original starting directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

You need to find the PID of the process, and then

```
ls -l /proc/$PID/cwd
```

For example, my shell has current directory `/home/igor`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 0 nov 11 21:49 /proc/6569/cwd -> /home/igor
```

The PID of the process you can find using `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep java.*AppJava.jar
```

Comment: That tells you where the *current* working directory is, not the cwd when the process started.

Comment: @mpez0: Strictly speaking, you are right, but I'm not sure that it is possible at all, what the process current directory was. Of course you can use `strace` and/or other audit methods.